# Serializing FileSystemWatcher Object

Tags: c#, serialization, filesystemwatcher

I want to store the FileSystemWatcher object in sqlite database for future reference but the getting the following exception on serializing the object

"Type 'System.IO.FileSystemWatcher' in Assembly 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable."

Here is the code

```
            MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream();
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(memorystream, FSWatcher);
            byte[] yourBytesToDb = memorystream.ToArray();
```

Thanks and Regards,
Haseena

Comment: That means you can't serialize the `FileSystemWatcher`, period. That being said, I don't really see a question here...?

Comment: So.. the error tells you what the exact problem is. Why not just store its properties in db columns? Why must you serialize the entire object?

Comment: Thats because `FSWatcher` is not serializable. What is your question?

Comment: What kind of information do you want to preserve and why?

Comment: I am working on a backup tool and using file system watcher for new added and changed file event.I want to preserve the objects for stopping the filewatcher event if someone delete the folder or the extension to be backed up. so what could be the right way to preserve the objects?

Answer (score 0):

Use the XML one

```
public static void SaveAsXML(Object A, string FileName)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(A.GetType());
    using (var textWriter = new StreamWriter(FileName))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, A);
        textWriter.Close();
    }
}

public static T LoadFromXML<T>(string FileName) where T : class
{
    if (File.Exists(FileName))
    {
        using (var textReader = new StreamReader(FileName))
        {
            var deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)(deserializer.Deserialize(textReader));
        }
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? This shouldn't work either since it's not marked as serializable!

Comment: the [SerializableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is just important for Binary Serialization! The XML Serialization works completely Different

Comment: getting the below exception using SaveAsXML method There was an error reflecting type 'System.IO.FileSystemWatcher'